# Python Multiprocessing in web crawler

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, beautifulsoup, multiprocessing, web-crawler

1. I am trying to implement multiprocessing in my web crawler, what I usually see online is sending the url as args into the function of map or map_async or apply_asyn. The data I am crawling is in the table, thus, I extract them by doing two times beautifulsoup find_all for row and column. Since the data I am crawling sometime is in one page which only require one url. I try to use the return list from Find_all as args for map_async, but the error occur showing ***"Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stackoverflow."***

The error occurred on the following line

```
return_list = pool.map_async(func, Species_all_recorded_data_List)
```

How could I solve it or where should the multiprocessing be implemented will be better?

[image]
[image]

2. The second problem is that if I put some code above the function **crawl_all_data_mp**, when it execute the pool = Pool(), all the code above will execute. I solved it by simply move all the other code under that function. It might not be correct since I still can't really run the code due to the first error.

Looking for your advice

My code:

**(1) Function to call for web crawling**

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import csv
import os.path
from os import path
from Index import *
from Dragonfly import *
import codecs
from multiprocessing import Process, Value
 
#\ multiprocessing ver
def multiprocessing_row_data(Web_rawl_Species_family_name, Web_rawl_Species_name, Total_num, Limit_CNT, expecting_CNT, oldID, page, Species_all_record_data_Data_Set):
    global DataCNT, stop_crawl_all_data_mp
    tmp_List = Species_all_record_data_Data_Set.find_all('td')
    # End condition
    # 1.no data in next page
    # 2.for update to find unti the old data by inspecting its ID
    # 3.if it count over the the limit count  
    id = tmp_List[0].text
    if (len(id) == 0) or (DataCNT >= expecting_CNT)or (DataCNT >= Limit_CNT):
        print(' --Finish crawl--' + ' crawl to page: ' + str(page) + ", ID: " + id + ", count: " + str(DataCNT))
        stop_crawl_all_data_mp = True
        raise StopIteration
    # access the same value in memory when doing multiprocessing 
    with DataCNT.getlock():
        DataCNT.value += 1

    response_DetailedInfo = session.post(general_url + Detailed_discriptions_url + id, headers=headers)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(response_DetailedInfo.text, 'html.parser')
    print("Current finished datas >> " + str(DataCNT.value) + " /" + str(Total_num) + " (" + str(DataCNT.value * 100 / Total_num) + "%)", end='\r')
    
    return DetailedTableInfo(tmp_List[0].text, tmp_List[1].text, tmp_List[2].text, tmp_List[3].text, tmp_List[4].text, tmp_List[5].text, tmp_List[7].text, tmp_List[6].text,
                                        soup2.find(id='R_LAT').get('value'),
                                        soup2.find(id='R_LNG').get('value'),
                                        Web_rawl_Species_family_name,
                                        Web_rawl_Species_name,
                                        soup2.find(id='R_MEMO').get('value'))





def crawl_all_data_mp(Web_rawl_Species_family_name, Web_rawl_Species_name, Total_num, Limit_CNT, expecting_CNT, oldID):
    page = 0
    DataList = []

    while not stop_crawl_all_data_mp:
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
        Species_all_recorded_data = session.post( general_url +
                                                species_all_record_data_first_url +
                                                species_all_record_data_page_url + str(page) +
                                                species_all_record_data_species_url +
                                                Species_class_key[Web_rawl_Species_family_name] +
                                                Species_key[Web_rawl_Species_name],
                                                headers=headers)    
        soup = BeautifulSoup(Species_all_recorded_data.text, 'html.parser')
        Species_all_recorded_data_List = soup.find_all(id='theRow')
        func = partial(multiprocessing_row_data, Web_rawl_Species_family_name, Web_rawl_Species_name, Total_num, Limit_CNT, expecting_CNT, oldID, page)
        return_list = pool.map_async(func, Species_all_recorded_data_List)
        DataList.append(list(filter(None, return_list.get())))

        page += 1  

    # make sure whe main is finished, subfunctions still keep rolling on 
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    return [DataList, page]
```

**(2) main**

it goes wrong on the following line for calling the function above

```
     [datatmpList, page] = crawl_all_data_mp(Input_species_famliy, Input_species, Total_num, limit_cnt, expecting_CNT, oldID)
```

the main code:

```
# --main--
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
    
        # setting
        Input_species_famliy = "細蟌科"
        Input_species = "四斑細蟌"
        limit_cnt = 6000
        folder = 'Crawl_Data\\' + Species_class_key[Input_species_famliy]
        File_name = folder + "\\" + Species_class_key[Input_species_famliy] + Species_key[Input_species] +'.csv'
        oldID = 0
        oldData_len = 0
    
        print("--Start crawl-- " + Input_species_famliy + " " + Input_species)
        print("[folder]: " + folder)
        stop_crawl_all_data_mp = False
    
    
        # check the file exist or not
        file_check = path.exists(current_path + "\\" + File_name)
    
        # get the Old ID
        if file_check:
            file_size = os.stat(current_path + "\\" + File_name).st_size
            if not file_size == 0:
                with open(File_name, newline='', errors = "ignore") as F:
                    R = csv.reader(F)
                    oldData = [line for line in R]
                    oldID = oldData[0][0]
                    oldData_len = len(oldData)-1
    
        # login     
        Login_Web(myaccount, mypassword)
    
        # find the total number of the species_input (expect executed one time)
        Species_total_num_Dict = Find_species_total_data()
    
    
        # get the data
        Total_num = int(Species_total_num_Dict[Input_species])
        #[datatmpList, page] = crawl_all_data(Input_species_famliy, Input_species, Total_num, limit_cnt, oldID)
    
    
        expecting_CNT = Total_num - oldData_len  # get the total number of data need to be update ot crawl
        [datatmpList, page] = crawl_all_data_mp(Input_species_famliy, Input_species, Total_num, limit_cnt, expecting_CNT, oldID)
    
        Data = []
        for Data_tmp in datatmpList:
            Data.append([Data_tmp.SpeciesFamily,
                    Data_tmp.Species,
                    Data_tmp.IdNumber,
                    Data_tmp.Dates,
                    Data_tmp.Times,
                    Data_tmp.User,
                    Data_tmp.City,
                    Data_tmp.Dictrict,
                    Data_tmp.Place,
                    Data_tmp.Altitude,
                    Data_tmp.Latitude,
                    Data_tmp.Longitude,
                    Data_tmp.Description
                    ])
    
        #auto make the directories
        newDir = current_path + "\\" + folder
        if (not os.path.isdir(newDir)):
            os.mkdir(newDir)
    
    
    
        # 'a' stands for append, which can append the new data to old one
        with open(File_name, mode='a', newline='', errors = "ignore") as employee_file:
            employee_writer = csv.writer(employee_file, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            # init , for there is no file exists or the file is empty
            if ((not file_check) or (file_size == 0)):
                employee_writer.writerow(CSV_Head)
                employee_writer.writerows(Data)
    
            # for inserting the data into the old one    
            else:
                for i in range(0, len(Data)):
                    oldData.insert(i, Data[i])
                employee_writer.writerows(oldData)
```